# ng-bootstrap not displaying tooltip

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to display a tooltip. I went to ng-bootstrap and integrated that code. Getting console error.

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for 
NgbTooltipConfig!
Error: No provider for NgbTooltipConfig!
at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9492)
at NgModuleRef_.get (core.es5.js:10562)
at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11050)
at createClass (core.es5.js:10920)
```

Added these lines in app.module.ts

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [    
    NgbModule
  ]
})
```

Installed ng-bootstrap using command

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should import `NgbModule.forRoot()` not `NgbModule`.

> The exact method will be slightly different for the root (top-level)
>   module for which you should end up with the code similar to (notice
>   `NgbModule.forRoot()`):
>
> ```
> import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
>
> @NgModule({
>   declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
>   imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
>   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
> })
> export class AppModule {
> }
> ```
>
> Other modules in your application can simply import `NgbModule`:
>
> ```
> import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
>
> @NgModule({
>   declarations: [OtherComponent, ...],
>   imports: [NgbModule, ...]
> })
> export class OtherModule {
> }
> ```

For more details , please read :

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

---

Here is the working example of tooltip :

http://plnkr.co/edit/AVylfgSqv5iLVi73LGz7?p=preview

Please compare your code with it.

Comment: After importing NgbModule.forRoot(), console error gone but not displaying tooltip. I am using only one module

Comment: @Veera, Congrats , your issue is solved now the error you are getting is might be related to coding , I think you should post another question for that.  Will you please accpet the answer and also upvote it?

Comment: please suggest fix for that also, not able to display tooltip

Comment: @Veera, we need to check your code how you write it, without showing that How can we suggest the solution, just do one thing post another question with code and plnkr link , so others can also help.

Comment: Other than app.module.ts, I added code in html <input ngbTooltip="Zip Code" id="zipCode" type="text">. Code side I added those only.

Comment: `<input ngbTooltip="Zip Code" id="zipCode" type="text">` is 100% correct.Please create a plnkr of your code, so we can check for the bug

Comment: Issue with css after adding bootstrap css, its working.

Answer (score 3):

add NgbTooltipConfig to providers

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [    
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [
     NgbTooltipConfig
  ]
})
```

and also add this css to your style.css

```
.tooltip{
  opacity:1!important;
}
```

Comment: I didn;t need to  add NgbTooltipConfig as a provider, but inspired by this, my (admittedly hacky) solution, which did make my tooltip show was                                                                  ::ng-deep ngb-tooltip-window{
  opacity:1!important;
 }