# ng-bootstrap not displaying tooltip despite following instructions in other answers to this question

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

In https://github.com/jimshowalter/vocabutron/blob/master/src/app/add-word/add-word.component.html. Following the instructions in the answer to [ng-bootstrap not displaying tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264723/ng-bootstrap-not-displaying-tooltip) doesn't work. It must be something stupidly obvious, but I don't see it.

Comment: Can you post the error message and the code instead of the link?

Answer (score 1):

It is showing the tooltip with 'opacity:0', so it is invisible to our eyes. Add 'tooltipClass' property and add 'opacity: 1;' to that class. For example:

add-word.component.html:

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!wordForm.form.valid" placement="bottom" ngbTooltip="Use this to add word to learn later" tooltipClass="opacity-1">Learn Later</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!wordForm.form.valid" (click)="learn()" placement="bottom" ngbTooltip="Use this to add word you've already learned" tooltipClass="opacity-1">I've Learned It</button>
```

styles.css:

```
.opacity-1 { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: Thank you! That's an odd default.

Comment: Agree but it might be required for some other use cases.